# How to display textboxes based on selected items in CheckboxList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I'm trying to display textboxes based on the checkboxlist items that the user has selected. I have 15 items in my checkboxlist with a textbox which corresponds to each when selected. I've made this code but I am unsure how to proceed. My goal is to look through the items in my checkboxlist and whenever it finds a selected item, it will make visible the div which displays the textbox. The textbox will have almost the same name as it's check box list equivalent. My problem is Im not quite sure how to take that value and making it so that it looks for the textbox control with the same name and display.

This is what I have so far:

```
{
        foreach(ListItem item in cblReasonSeekingServices.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected == true)
            {
                string strControlName = item.Value;
                

                string strSpaceRemoved = Regex.Replace(strControlName, " ", "");

                

                ((TextBox)FindControl("pnl" + strSpaceRemoved)).Visible = true;

            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I'm able to run the code now without any error messages however, the textbox control does not display. Am I missing anything?

```
            foreach(ListItem item in cblReasonSeekingServices.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected == true)
            {
                string strControlName = item.Value;

                string strSpaceRemoved = Regex.Replace(strControlName, " ", "");

                string test = ("tb" + strSpaceRemoved);

                TextBox tBox = this.Master.FindControl("body").FindControl("tbBehavioralDifficulties") as TextBox;

                tBox.Visible = true;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hum, ok, say we have 5 text box, and then

So, say this:

```
        <div style="float:left;width:20%">

            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
            </asp:CheckBoxList>

        </div>

        <div style="float:left;width:20%">

            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="Text1"> </asp:TextBox> <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text="Text2"> </asp:TextBox> <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text="Text3"> </asp:TextBox> <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text="Text4"> </asp:TextBox> <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text="Text5"> </asp:TextBox> <br />
        </div>

        <div style="clear:both;height:20px">
        </div>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show selected" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

And code behind is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                ListItem OneItem = new ListItem("Choice #" + i, i.ToString());
                CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(OneItem);

                // hide the text box
                string sTbox = "TextBox" + i;
                TextBox Tbox = Page.FindControl(sTbox) as TextBox;
                Tbox.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem Choice in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            string sTbox = "TextBox" + Choice.Value;
            TextBox Tbox = Page.FindControl(sTbox) as TextBox;
            Tbox.Visible = Choice.Selected;
        }
    }
```

So, we get this then - select a few check box, hit button:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it still didn't work for me. I did fine this solution which doesn;t cause errors however, the textbox control wont display.

Comment: Gee, then you have to post some of your markup. We somewhat guessing here. The above posted code does work fine. So, as always, each case might need a bit of tweaking, so seeing at least "some" of your markup would help boatloads here. Also, use caution with visible, since any control that has visiable = false is NOT rendered, or sent to the client side browser. (as a result, JavaScript/jQuery etc. can't operate on such controls). So, additonal issues such as if you need any client side code comes into play here. (if yes, then you are better to use style=display:none in place of visible).

Comment: My apologies. I forgot to mention that I edited my code above.

Comment: My apologies I should have stated that from the start. So the user goes on a form which contains a checkboxlist. The checkbox list has a corresponding textbox that when the user selects an item on the checkbox list, the textbox will appear after the checkboxlist. So if the user selects 4 out the choices on the checkboxlist, there would be 4 textboxes below the checkboxlist wherein the user can elaborate more as to those are their choices.

Comment: I've set my checboxlist to AutoPostBack="true" and an OnSelectedIndexChanged, which is where I placed the code in from above.

Comment: Sorry, my comments about a pop dialog were for a different post! - my bad!. I not sure the regex needs to be used here. All you have to do is match up the textbox name(s). I assume they are numbered with some prefix?? I used Textbox1...N, but I don't think you need regex here - just a simple replace should/would suffice. Keep in mind checkbox list has both a value, and a text display.